# React eCharts library/type = line - markArea, i want to stop marking the area whenever there is a specific value between the two points

Tags: reactjs, linechart, echarts

```
markArea : {
  data : 
    [
      [
         { 
            xAxis : mockData[0],
         },            
         {
            xAxis : mockData[mockData.length-1] ,
         },
      ],
   ],
```

Between the two items there are some values that i want every time that the `markArea` is hitting them to stop marking and start marking again at the next element of `mockData` that is bigger or equal of the hitting point. For example if `mockData = [0 , 1 , 2 , ... , 100]` and the hitting points are `[0.5,1.5,2.5,..,99.5]` i want to mark the Areas `[[0,0.4],[0.6-1.4],[1.6,2.4],...,[98.6,99.4],[99.6-100]]`.

P.S. : The `mockData` array is very large.

I tried to modify the `mockData` array to exclude the areas that contains the hitting points but the `mockData` array is very large and is causing perfomance issues